# Accidentally used Prestone 50/50 coolant (green) in my 2004 VW Golf with pink coolant

Tags: vw, golf

I'm pretty sure I had only used G12 prior. I bought the Prestone 50/50 "goes with everything" coolant because my coolant light had come on. I remembered not to mix colors as soon as I started pouring it.

Should I flush the whole thing? Can I just continue topping of with G12 or distilled water? The level is way below the minimum line.

Comment: How much did you actually add @NilsGuillermin? A small trickle? A few liters? Amount is important.

Comment: @GdD I poured for about three seconds. Not enough to top it off at all it’s still way below minimum.

Comment: 3 seconds? Don't worry about it, just get the pink stuff and top it up. I'd be looking into why you're losing coolant personally.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing coolants in newish VWs is problematic, as combining the stock G12/G13 pink coolant with green other-manufacturer coolant can lead to the formation of thickening and sludge within the engine's coolant passages.

If you plan to keep the car, you should drain, flush, and refill.

Comment: I'm not doubting you @David, but I'd be interested in seeing your sources on that.

Comment: @GdD I was the original owner of a 2001 B5 VW Passat, and I hung out on passatworld.com. There are *lots* of threads there on what happens when coolants are mixed. I used only G12/G13 in mine; when I sold the car last spring after eighteen years, the cooling system was sparking clean internally.  This page has a more scientific explanation: https://www.quora.com/What-will-actually-happen-when-G12-coolant-is-mixed-with-regular-types-including-with-those-that-claim-to-mix-with-ANY-type-of-antifreeze. Perhaps some "universal" coolants would be OK, but I thought using them not worth the risk.

Answer (score 0):

Prestone specifications state that its' patented unique formula is compatible with all other colors of anti-freeze. While I think they wouldn't make a statement like this likely, compatible may not mean it is the best choice.  I would have no reservations of using Prestone  to top off the system. If I was doing a complete flush and refill I would use the factory recommended product. It is possible that it contains special additives the manufacturer has determined increase the reliability and durability of the cooling system.